# C# Android how do i get log on real device

Tags: c#, android

I made an android app, it works on emulator, but when I test it on real device it just crashes instantly. I already tried disabling shared runtime and fast deployment, but it does not seem to work.

I tried searching on google, but i just cant seem to find any answer. When I test it on a real device I just export the .apk file, to the phone via usb. I export the signed apk file.

Is there a way to get the log on the real device, so I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [adb (Android Debug Brigde)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html). To get the log of a connected device just type:

```
adb logcat
```

[Documentation for logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html)